# SQL Server NULLS: duplicate last known value in table

Tags: sql-server, duplicates, isnull

I need some advice.

I have a column with nulls in a field at a particular time period.

```
Name     Date
-----    -----
Cat      1/1/2012
Dog      1/2/2012
Fish     1/3/2012
NULL     1/4/2012
Goat     1/5/2012
NULL     1/6/2012
Sheep    1/7/2012
```

In the example above, how would I write a SQL statement to select the last known value for column Name whenever there is a null value in the column?

For instance I'd like the table to look like this:

```
Name      Date
-----    -----
Cat        1/1/2012
Dog        1/2/2012
Fish       1/3/2012
Fish       1/4/2012
Goat       1/5/2012
Goat       1/6/2012
Sheep      1/7/2012
```

---

Would this pseudo-code work?

```
Select 
isnull(Name, "Select Name from Table where Date = GetDate() - 1")
,Date
From Table
```

Comment: Not if there are multiple rows with the same date.

Comment: If I create a primary key with enough fields to make each value unique, would I be able to use a select statement inside of the isnull function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [v is original, v2 is calculated new value] :

```
DECLARE @table table(v varchar(10), d varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @table 
SELECT 'Cat','1/1/2012' UNION
SELECT 'Dog','1/2/2012' UNION
SELECT 'Fish','1/3/2012' UNION
SELECT NULL,'1/4/2012' UNION
SELECT 'Goat','1/5/2012' UNION
SELECT NULL,'1/6/2012' UNION
SELECT 'Sheep','1/7/2012'


SELECT A.v, A.d, ISNULL(A.v,B.v) V2
FROM @table A
OUTER APPLY (   SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM @table 
                WHERE d < A.d
                AND v IS NOT NULL
                ORDER BY d desc) B
order by d
```

Comment: Hey rs. What do I do if the value that I need isn't always at the 'top'?

Comment: can you post some sample data.